# Magento 1.9.3.6 - Disable cache for a specific module

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, full-page-cache, block-cache

could someone explain to me how to disable the cache of a specific module?

I have this code in cms static block:

```
{{block type="filterproducts/featured_home_list" name="featured_list" product_count="8" column_count="4" aspect_ratio="1" image_width="189" image_height="189" template="filterproducts/grid.phtml"}}
```

the featured products do not rotate when refresh the page but if I disable modules cache all works fine.

I tried to add this code in my local xml file

```
 <layout>
    <default>
     <reference name="featured_list">
        <action method="setCacheLifetime" />
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

OR

```
 <block type="filterproducts/featured_home_list" name="featured_list">
        <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
        </block>
```

but no luck.